A property of $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions
Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and let $x_0\in P$ where $P$ is a perfect set.
I want proof that $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ with $\lvert f(x)-f(y)-f'(y)(x-y) \rvert<\varepsilon\lvert  x-y\rvert$ $\forall x,y\in P$ ,$\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\delta$,$\lvert y-x_0\rvert<\delta$.

My attempt: let $\varepsilon>0$.
Because $F'$ is continous in $x_0$, exists $\delta>0$ with $\lvert f'(x)-f'(x_0)\rvert<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ , $\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\delta$.
Let now $x,y\in P$, $x\neq y$ with $\lvert x-x_0\rvert<\delta $ and $\lvert y-x_0\rvert<\delta$.
For MVT theorem exists $x'\in (x,y)\cup (y,x)$ with $f'(x')=\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$.
Then  $\lvert f(x)-f(y)-f'(y)(x-y)\rvert=\biggl\lvert \dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(y)\biggr\rvert\lvert x-y\rvert=\lvert f'(x')-f'(y)\rvert\lvert x-y\rvert<[ \lvert f'(x')-f'(x_0)\rvert+\lvert f'(x_0)-f'(y)\rvert] \lvert x-y\rvert$.
I control $\lvert f'(x_0)-f'(y)\rvert<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ because $\lvert y-x_0\rvert<\delta$.
How i can control instead $\lvert f'(x')-f'(x_0)\rvert$?
I have to distinguish position of $x,y,x_0,x'$ to evaluate $\lvert x'-x_0\rvert$ or the hypothesis that $P$  is perfect is relevant?
Thanks in advance.

Because $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and $|y-x_0|<\delta$, you also have $|x'-x_0|<\delta$. I don't think that $P$ being perfect is relevant.

Isn't this just Taylor's theorem?

Taylor's theorem has a fixed point $a$: $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) + R_1(x)(x - a)$ with $\lim_{x \to a} R_1(x) = 0$  i.e. $\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ with $\lvert R_1(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\delta$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(y) + \int_{0}^{1}f'(y + t(x - y))\,dt \cdot (x - y) \\
&= f(y) + f'(y)(x - y) + \int_{0}^{1}(f'(y + t(x - y)) - f'(y))\,dt \cdot (x - y). \\
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
f(x) - f(y) - f'(y)(x - y) &= \int_{0}^{1}(f'(y + t(x - y)) - f'(y))\,dt \cdot (x - y).
\end{align}
Now let
$r(y, x) = \int_{0}^{1}(f'(y + t(x - y)) - f'(y))\,dt$. You can show that $r$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $r(x_0, x_0) = 0$.
